Uniform convergence of $f_n(x) = \frac{\ln(1+\frac{x}{n})}{x+1}$
Basically i have a problem proving the sequence in the title 1. Uniformly converges on a closed interval $[0,a]$ where $a > 0$ and 2. Uniformly converges on $[0,\infty).$ So far i have found the limit it converges to pointwise, its pretty clear it goes to 0. Then i tried the uniform convergence on [0,a], but i cannot find anything that i could use with the Weierstrass theorem. Then i tried the other way, of calculating the supremum of $|f_n(x) - f(x)| = |f_n(x)|$, but after calculating the derivative it appears to me as though the derivative doesnt have a zero. So what could i try next. I know that for a fact it is uniformly convergent or at least thats what the solution says so i didnt try to prove it isnt, i just dont know how to proceed

It's not exactly clear what you mean with $a$. You want this to converge uniformly on $[0,a]$ where $0<a<2$?

consider bounding below $|x+1|$ and bounding above $\ln(1+x/n)$..

Ohh, thanks for the clarification @SineoftheTime

@AnCar it says simply that "a" is a real number > 0

@fGDu94 i tried doing that but i always get a too harsh bound, cause i mean idk how to really bound x+1 below, the only option i see would be x, but i cant have x in the bound if i want to use  the weierstrass theorem

how about just $1$

Then it goes to infinity as n goes to infinity, but i think i just found the solution. I realized there are hints on the back of the book and it says to use ln(1+t) <= t, so from there you can see that ln(1+x/n)/x+1 <= (x/n)/x+1 = x/n(x+1) and this goes to 0 as n approaches infinity and with this both 1. and 2. are probably proven?

We can use the bound $$g(t)=\ln(1+t)\leq t=h(t),\quad t\geq 0$$
which follows because $g(0)=0=h(0)$ and $g'(t)=\dfrac{1}{1+t}\leq 1=h'(t)$ for $t\geq 0$.
We then have that $$|f_n(x)|=f_n(x)=\dfrac{\ln(1+\frac{x}{n})}{x+1}\leq \dfrac{x}{n(x+1)}\leq \dfrac{1}{n},\quad x\geq 0$$
Thus, the convergence is indeed uniform on $[0,+\infty)$, and consequently on any interval $[0,a]$ with $a>0$ too.

Thanks everyone for your answers

Since $\log(1+z) \le z,$ we have for every $x\in[0,\infty)$ that $$0 \le f_n(x) \le \frac{x/n}{1+x} \le 1/n \implies \sup_{x\in[0,\infty)}| f_n(x)| \le \frac1n,$$ which clearly goes to $0$ as $n$ diverges.

Thank you everyone for your answers
